# Yarn run watch/dev not picking up changes

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a scenario where by im trying to make changes to Vue files and yarn run watch/dev has stopped working and tracking any changes made.

Im running a docker environment and any changes made after a successful yarn run dev are not being shown and also any changes made to my vue files are not triggering a rebuild in yarn run watch.

I have even tried yarn run watch-poll and that has also had no success.

Ill attached my webpack file and package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "cover": "cross-env NODE_ENV=coverage nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text npm run test:cover",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha-webpack --webpack-config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/unit/setup.js --recursive --glob \"*.spec.js\" 'tests/unit'",
    "test:cover": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/unit/setup.js --recursive --glob \"*.spec.js\" 'tests/unit' -- --compilers js:babel/register ",
    "test:single": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha-webpack --webpack-config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/unit/setup.js ",
    "e2e": "cypress run",
    "e2e-open": "cypress open"
  },
  "devD
```

Webpack file:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');
let webpack = require('webpack');
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
var isCoverage = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'coverage';

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@image': __dirname + '/resources/images/',
            '@svg': __dirname + '/resources/images/svgs',
            '@theme': __dirname + '/resources/images/svgs/' + process.env.THEME_NAME,
        },
    },
});
const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
mix.extend('gmShared', webpackConfig => {
    const { rules } = webpackConfig.module;

    rules
        .filter(rule => rule.exclude && rule.exclude.toString() === '/(node_modules|bower_components)/')
        .forEach(rule => (rule.exclude = /node_modules\/(?!(greenmotion-shared)\/).*/));
});
const plugins = [];
// plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin);
plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        API_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_BASE_URL),
        AUTH_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.AUTH_URL),
        RDPS_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.RDPS_BASE_URL),
        HOOYU_REDIRECT_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.HOOYU_REDIRECT_URL),
        BUGSNAG_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.BUGSNAG_KEY),
        ALGOLIA_APP_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID),
        ALGOLIA_READ_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.ALGOLIA_READ_KEY),
        ALGOLIA_PREFIX: JSON.stringify(process.env.ALGOLIA_PREFIX),
        ROUTER_MODE: JSON.stringify(process.env.ROUTER_MODE),
        STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY),
        DEV_MODE: JSON.stringify(process.env.DEV_MODE || false),
        IS_DEMO_MODE: JSON.stringify(process.env.IS_DEMO_MODE || false),
        ENABLE_DEMO_SHORTCUTS: process.env.ENABLE_DEMO_SHORTCUTS || false,
        ANALYTICS_URCHIN: JSON.stringify(process.env.ANALYTICS_URCHIN),
        MINIMUM_APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.MINIMUM_APP_VERSION),
        SOURCE_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.SOURCE_ID) || 1,
        PUSHER_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.PUSHER_KEY),
        PUSHER_AUTH_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.PUSHER_AUTH_URL),
        SUPPORT_TELEPHONE: JSON.stringify(process.env.SUPPORT_TELEPHONE),
        SUPPORT_TELEPHONE_LABEL: JSON.stringify(process.env.SUPPORT_TELEPHONE_LABEL),
        SUPPORT_EMAIL: JSON.stringify(process.env.SUPPORT_EMAIL),
    })
);
plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/));

if (!['test', 'coverage'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['common'],
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            minChunks: function (module, count) {
                // Extract the libs in node_modules
                return false;
            },
        })
    );
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['common'],
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            minChunks: function (module, count) {
                // Extract the libs in node_modules
                return (
                    (module.context && module.context.includes('node_modules')) ||
                    (module.resource && module.resource.includes('bootstrap.js')) ||
                    count > 3
                );
            },
        })
    );
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'manifest',
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            chunks: 'infinity',
        })
    );
}
plugins.push(
    new GenerateSW({
        swDest: 'sw.js',
        // skipWaiting: true,
        importsDirectory: 'sw-assets',
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                urlPattern: '/',
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: '/bookings',
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: '/profile',
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: '/search',
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: '/login',
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: new RegExp('.*.js'),
                handler: 'networkFirst',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: new RegExp('.*.css'),
                handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: new RegExp('.*.svg'),
                handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
            },
            {
                urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://api.staging.greenmotion.com/api/user'),
                handler: 'networkFirst',
                options: {
                    cacheName: 'api-cache',
                    cacheableResponse: {
                        statuses: [0, 200],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    })
);

Mix.listen('configReady', function (config) {
    const rules = config.module.rules;
    const targetRegex = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;

    for (let rule of rules) {
        if (rule.test.toString() == targetRegex.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
            break;
        }
    }
});

let webpackRules = [
    {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
];;

if (isCoverage) {
    webpackRules = webpackRules.concat(
        {
            test: /\.(js|ts)/,
            include: path.resolve('resources/js'), // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, after ts-loader runs
            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
            query: {
                esModules: true
            },
            exclude: [
                /node_modules/,
                /tests/
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            include: path.resolve('resources/js'),
            exclude: [
                /node_modules/,
                /tests/
            ],
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [
                  ['es2015', { targets: "defaults" }]
                ],
                plugins: [
                    "syntax-dynamic-import",
                    "transform-class-properties",
                    "transform-object-rest-spread"
                ],
              }
            }
          }
    );
}
mix.webpackConfig({
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        publicPath: '',
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: {
        rules: webpackRules,
    },
});

mix.setPublicPath('public')
    .gmShared()
    .copy('resources/webroot/', 'public/')
    .copy('resources/images/', 'public/images/')
    .copy('resources/font/', 'public/font/')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/');

if (!['test', 'coverage'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
    mix.version()
        .copy('resources/html/index.html', 'public/')
        .then(stats => {
            let manifest = require('./public/mix-manifest.json');
            let from = [];
            let to = [];
            Object.keys(manifest).forEach(key => {
                from.push(key);
                to.push(manifest[key]);
            });

            let changes = replace.sync({
                files: 'public/index.html',
                from: from,
                to: to,
            });

            let missedFiles = replace.sync({
                files: 'public/index.html',
                from: /{{mix\('(.*)'\)}}/gim,
                to: '$1',
            });
        })
        .browserSync({
            server: './public',
            proxy: null,
            notify: false,
            open: false,
        })
        .sourceMaps();
} else {
    mix.copy('resources/html/index.html', 'public/')
        .then(stats => {
            let manifest = require('./public/mix-manifest.json');
            let from = [];
            let to = [];
            Object.keys(manifest).forEach(key => {
                from.push(key);
                to.push(manifest[key]);
            });

            let changes = replace.sync({
                files: 'public/index.html',
                from: from,
                to: to,
            });

            let missedFiles = replace.sync({
                files: 'public/index.html',
                from: /{{mix\('(.*)'\)}}/gim,
                to: '$1',
            });
        })
        .browserSync({
            server: './public',
            proxy: null,
            notify: false,
            open: false,
        })

        .sourceMaps();
}
```